# Conversion of dates in strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, date-format

I want to change the format of a string like the example shown below.

```
input : `June 03` output : `2014/06/03`
input : `11-12` output : `2014/12/11`
input : `11-12-2014` output : `2014/12/11`
```

I initially tried like this:

```
 Format(CDate(mskExpDate.Text), "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

It's worked for `June 03` and `11-12-2014`, but if I enter `11-12` it returns `2014/11/12`

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I get the code to work for all formatting cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to try and parse the three formats of date and return the first one that can be parsed using [Date.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) with [custom date and time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Function ParseMyDate(dateString As String) As Date
    Dim d As Date
    If Date.TryParseExact(dateString, "MMMM dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then Return d
    If Date.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then Return d
    If Date.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then Return d
    Return Nothing 'you could throw an exception here instead
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim d1 As Date = ParseMyDate("June 03")
    Dim d2 As Date = ParseMyDate("11-12")
    Dim d3 As Date = ParseMyDate("11-12-2014")

    Debug.WriteLine(d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
    Debug.WriteLine(d2.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
    Debug.WriteLine(d3.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

Output:

```
2014/06/03
2014/12/11
2014/12/11
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Its possible in single code like ` format(date,formatstring)` like that

Comment: I'm not sure if that was a question or a comment, but you cannot do that in one line of code, especially not using the format method

Comment: Then i have one doubt sir. before i use only the format string only that how that convert june 03 to 03/06-2014 but why its not convert 11-12 to 11-12-2014

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create some logic... and then specify the type of input your are giving the dateparse routine (I.e., where is the month, day, year etc...)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("datestring", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault)
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir. i want to convert `11-12` to `11-12-2014`. If i give date only its return date-currentmonth-currentyear like that sir

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you will have to treat the `11-12` format as a special case, like this:

```
Private Function ConvertDate(ByVal inputStringDate As String) As Date
    If inputStringDate.split("-").Length = 2 Then
        inputStringDate &= "-" & Now.Year
    End If
    Dim outputDate As Date = Format(CDate(inputStringDate), "yyyy/MM/dd")
    Return outputDate
End Function
```

Test:

```
    Dim inputStringDate1 As String = "June 03"
    Dim inputStringDate2 As String = "11-12"
    Dim inputStringDate3 As String = "11-12-2014"

    Dim date1 As Date = ConvertDate(inputStringDate1)
    ' date1 = #6/1/2003#
    Dim date2 As Date = ConvertDate(inputStringDate2)
    ' date2 = #12/11/2014#
    Dim date3 As Date = ConvertDate(inputStringDate3)
    ' date3 = #12/11/2014#
```